# How to select a dataframe from a list of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a list of dataframes and I want to select that dataframe which have maximum size.
My list looks like this:[image: list]

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe to need function `max`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, ..., dfn]
df = max(dfs, key=len)
```

Another solution, thanks @piRSquared:

```
print (max(dfs, key=lambda d: d.size))
```

Comment: `key=lambda d: d.size`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want can sort:

```
sorted_dfs=sorted(dfs,key=len)
```

Then to access maximum do `sorted_dfs[0]` and second `sorted_dfs[1]` and third `sorted_dfs[2]` and so on...

Can also do another way to sort:

```
sorted_dfs=sorted(dfs,key=lambda x: x.size)
```

Then can access elements the same way

Can also do another way to sort:

```
import numpy as np
sorted_dfs=sorted(dfs,key=np.size)
```

Then can access elements the same way